# How to filter day and date from database using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch day and date from database using PHP and MySQL. My table is below:

db_day:

```
day_id    day_name

  1        Monday

  2        Tuesday

  3        Wednsday

  4        Thursday

  5        Friday

  6        Saturday

  7        Sunday
```

The above is my day table.

db_special:

```
id    restname       date_from          date_to      day_from  day_to

 1     aaa           2016-09-22        2016-09-26      1         4

 2     bbb           2016-10-19        2016-10-28      2         5

 3     ccc           2016-10-18        2016-10-25      4         7
```

The above are my two table. Suppose user has the input `Tuesday` and it need to be fetched the value within date range from the above table.Here if user has the input only `Tuesday`,first it should calculate the day and date. If suppose today's day is `Friday` it will consider next `Tuesday` onwards.

Here user input is only `Tuesday` so it will calculate today's date `e.g-2016-10-21` and then will filter value from the above table. The expected result as per this example should be this row from the table:

`bbb           2016-10-19        2016-10-28      2         5`

How can I write the query to resolve this problem?

Comment: If user input is Tuesday what is the logic for selecting from db_special? Why if today date is 2016-10-21 the result should be `bbb           2016-10-22        2016-10-28      2         5`?

Comment: @krasipenkov : Because see the `day_from and day_to`. Its within Tuesday to friday` as per `db_day` table.

Comment: @krasipenkov : Here logic is if user input is `Tuesday` . Today's date should match with date range and input day will match with day range from the `db_special` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code:

```
// $db is PDO instance
// $userDay is user input day

$todayDayId = date('N');
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT day_id FROM db_day WHERE day_name=:userDay');
$stmt->execute([':userDay' => $userDay]);
$userDayId = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if($todayDayId > $userDayId) {
    $diff = (7-$todayDayId) + $userDayId;
}
else {
    $diff = $userDayId - $todayDayId;
}

$wantedDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$diff.' day'));

$pdoData = [
    ':wantedDate'  => $wantedDate,
    ':wantedDate2' => $wantedDate,
];
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, restname, date_from, date_to, day_from, day_to
                      FROM db_special
                      WHERE date_from>=:wantedDate AND date_to<=:wantedDate2');
$stmt->execute($pdoData);
$result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Let me to try this and let you know.